# How to log-in to a phpbb forum using python27ese?

Tags: python-2.7, urllib, urllib2, login-script

I modified a test script from [Python Docs](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/urllib2.html#urllib-howto) in order to attempt to login to a phpbbforum account and print the sourcecode of the viewonline.php page. However, the login was ignored "In order to view the online list you have to be registered and logged in".

This is the code I was working with:

```
import urllib
import urllib2

url = 'http://www.phpbbforum.whatever/viewonline.php?sg=0&sk=b&sd=d&start=0'
values = {'username' : 'the username',
      'password' : 'the password'}

data = urllib.urlencode(values)
req = urllib2.Request(url, data)
response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
the_page = response.read()
print the_page
```

Where `'the username'` was replaced with my username and `'the password'` was replaced with my password. I'd really like some help fine tuning this code so that it'll login and view the online list printing it to console.

Tried the above code, tried `Username` and `username` tried `Password` and `password`. The source code says `"password"` and `"username"` as the code references to those boxes without caps.

I expected it to go to the "you have been logged in" page then redirect to viewonline.php and print it. It appears that it is just loading the original login page unaltered as if it didn't even notice a username and password were attached.

Also I realize it will require loading several pages after this request as it will first go to "you have been logged in please wait while we redirect you" before the viewonline.php page. I'm not sure how to achieve getting to that point, help please?

Answer (score 0):

I jumped the gun here, I was able to login and view the page. I needed to set the cookie without that it forgot I was logged in on read. not only that I forgot to tell it to load the actual page I wanted to read after the fact to bypass the "you have been successfully logged in" page.

I found some other code on stack exchange that helped. At: [Login to a phpbb forum python stack exchange](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11834895/login-to-a-phpbb-forum-cookie-changed)

after that I edited the code so it looked like this:

```
import urllib, urllib2, cookielib, re, time

username = "my username"
password = "my password"
loginsite = "http://www.phpbbforum.whatever"
ok_tekst = "You have been successfully logged in."        
cj = cookielib.CookieJar()
opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(cj))
login_data = urllib.urlencode({'username' : username, 'password' : password, 
                            "autologin" : "on", 'login' : 'Login'})

resp = opener.open(loginsite, login_data)
if ok_tekst in resp.read():
    print "Login successfull"
    print "Cookies are:"
    for cookie in cj:
        print cookie
    url = "http://www.phpbbforum.whatever/viewonline.php?sg=1"
    response = opener.open(url)
    the_page = response.read()
    open("F:/Pingas.txt", 'w').write(the_page)
```

The removal of the logout statement and the inclusion of loading a second page with the active cookie got me a complete output of the source code of the viewonline.php page.